# How to add Scroll bars to UIComponent in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, scrollbar, uicomponents

I have following situation.

```
<mx:Canvas id="canvas" height="100%" width="100%">
<mx:UIComponent id="chart" width="100%" height="100%"/> 
</mx:Canvas>
```

Now there is one SVGDocument component which gets added as a child to above UIComponent. It is basically svg image. I have implemented zoom functionality for this. So, on mouse scroll up and mouse scroll down, SVGDocument element is getting zoomed in and zoomed out respectively. I want to add scroll bars to UIComponent 'chart' so that whenever SVGDocument gets large enough, scrollbars will appear. Currently I am not finding any way to add this. Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You need to position the `UIComponent` at (0,0) on the `Canvas` and size the `Canvas` to match the SVG image width and height.  Wrap the `Canvas` in a `Box` and you'll have scroll bars when needed.  It's the `Canvas` size that makes the `Box` show or hide the scroll bars.

```
<mx:Box width="100%" height="100%">
  <mx:Canvas id="canvas"><!-- set width & height to match SVG image -->
    <mx:UIComponent id="chart" x="0" y="0"/>
  </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall use `Scroller` and `Group` components(for spark) or some kind of `Box` for mx if you don't want to manage scrollbars manually.
Don't forget to limit `Scroller` or `Box` size to forbid them extension outside their parent borders.
If you want to have custom scrolling behavior, you can manually set `Group`'s `clipAndEnableScrolling` property to true and deal with its `viewport` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am using flex 3.0 and there is no scroller in there.I tried to use box but still scroll bars were not appearing. Seems like UIComponent does not report its height and width to its parent.

Comment: Did you remove `width="100%" height="100%"`? It forces `UIComponent` to fit your box.